# Fazer uma consulta em um nó especifico de um arquivo XML no c#

Tags: c#, xml

Tenho um sistema de login no C# e um seguinte arquivo XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Usuarios>
    <Usuario>
        <User_ID>001</User_ID>
        <Password>010309</Password>
        <Password_Change_Date>00/00/00</Password_Change_Date>
        <User_Login>admteste</User_Login>
        <User_RG>00000002</User_RG>
        <User_Status>Normal</User_Status>
        <User_Profile>4</User_Profile>
    </Usuario>
    <Usuario>
        <User_ID>002</User_ID>
        <Password>01234</Password>
        <Password_Change_Date>01/10/2019</Password_Change_Date> 
        <User_Login>pbteste</User_Login>
        <User_RG>00000005</User_RG>
        <User_Status>Inicial</User_Status>
        <User_Profile>3</User_Profile>
    </Usuario>  
    <Usuario>
        <User_ID>003</User_ID>
        <Password>01234</Password>
        <Password_Change_Date>21/1/2013</Password_Change_Date>
        <User_Login>pbteste2</User_Login>
        <User_RG>00000023</User_RG>
        <User_Status>Bloqueado</User_Status>
        <User_Profile>3</User_Profile>
    </Usuario>
</Usuarios>
```

Em meu sistema,quando o usuario apertar o botão Login preciso verificar neste XML se o nome de login existe neste arquivo e se a senha esta de acordo com o usuario, como posso fazer lendo apenas os nós User_Login e Password ?
Obrigado

Comment: Aconselho a procurares as opções aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752796/how-to-read-xml-in-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue o exemplo em XPATH para verificar se existe um node `Usuario` com o `User_Login` e `Password` desejados:

```
string usuario = "pbteste";
string senha = "01234x";

XmlNodeList nodeList
    = doc.SelectNodes("//Usuario[User_Login[text()='" + usuario + "'] and Password[text()='" + senha + "']]");

if(nodeList.Count == 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Usuário e/ou Senha estão incorretos");
```

Comment: O que este nodeList retorna, caso exista os dados no XML?

Comment: Perdão, eu não entendi muito bem o que eu faço com esta variavel nodeList

Comment: Se nodeList = 0, significa que não existe usuário com o login e senha informados. Vou alterar o texto para deixar isso claro.

Comment: Perfeito brother, muito obrigado era exatamente isso que precisava... agora por exemplo se eu precisasse pegar o User_RG deste usuário que logou, como faria? vc poderia me dar alguma dica? desculpe preciso fazer este trampo pra facul e sou bem leigo com XML

Comment: Use `nodeList[0].SelectNodes("User_RG")[0].InnerText`